# zshell says command not found in MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, zsh

I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.4. When I open zsh I get immediately

```
/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:104: command not found: mkdir
```

I understand that my terminal immediately executes the content of '/etc/zshrc' and '/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal' before it executes that of '~/.zshrc' in which I inserted the command

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"
```

In fact after those files are loaded by the terminal every command is reachable since I can go

```
me@mylaptop ~ % which locale
/usr/bin/locale
me@mylaptop ~ % which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
```

I tried to edit the files '/etc/zshrc' and '/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal' but I couldn't do it because the system says they are blocked even if I open their properties and change the rights for every group to read/write by opening the lock with the sudo password.

Comment: Why the `bash` tag?

Comment: You know the error message. You know the file and the line number, where the error occurs. Why don't you post that line (maybe with some context, such as 2 lines before and after)? From what you wrote, my guess is that the `locale` command is issued before the PATH has been setup. Since Apple decided to not allow users to fiddle with their /etc, it means that Apple messed this up, and I don't think you can doing something about it without breaking some Apple license agreement.

Comment: _I understand that my terminal immediately executes the content of '/etc/zshrc'_  : Not quite. If you read the zsh man-page, you will find that first of all /etc/zshenv is processed by zsh. In addition, AFIK some environment variables are set by the system even prior a process (i.e. zsh) has been started, and they may or may not contain a setting for PATH. See for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x) discussion.

Comment: I don't have the file '/etc/zshenv'. Moreover after reading the discussion you linked I verified that my '/etc/paths' file contains

/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

which contain the correct paths to the locale and mkdir commands. So I still don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you

Do not modify these two files '/etc/zshrc' and '/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal'

The problem should be that you messed up configuring your .zprofile or .zshrc

**On the premise that you have backed up these two files, try to delete the contents so that the terminal can run normally.You have to debug your .zshrc and/or .zprofile line by line.**

My problem was that I messed up configuring the .zprofile, I put the following in one line

```
export PATHeval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Change them to the following and it will be fine

```
export PATH
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

You can refer to the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75047323/etc-zshrc7-command-not-found-locale)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).